# Graffiti CMS - do I really need to 777 the entire install?

Tags: chmod, graffiticms

I am trying to install GraffitiCMS on my rackspacecloud account. It is mostly working, but it seems I pretty much have to set everything to 777 to get it to work? Is that even reasonable?

While I am not security expert, it seems that having to basically leave the door wide open to everyone in the world is not a great solution.

Am I misunderstanding what Graffiti needs? If it really needs that, can this product be seriously considered a viable option?

Comment: I think this belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of Graffiti CMS and your web server. In the past Graffiti has written directories and default.aspx files to support urls without extensions (i.e. mysite.com/post). This does require write/modify permissions for the account that your App Pool is running as to the root of your site. Typically this is the Network Service account. You do not need to give everyone elevated permissions.

However if you are using the latest open source version of Graffiti CMS on CodePlex, and IIS 7.0 or above, it uses URL routing and does *not* write directories/files for posts. In this scenario the service account would only need write permissions for the file storage folders.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Think that is it; using the newest version, IIS7, but I think it requires .net 3.5 w/SP1, and I don't think my hosting provider has it installed.

Answer (score 0):

will it break if you set it back after the installation? i think its just needed to write some static stuff like db connect into php files.

Comment: Like Kevin said, it depends upon the version and your setup. Without IIS7 and the latest version, it creates files for every post, to give you extensionless URLs. And what's this PHP you speak of??? Graffiti is 100% C# and Asp.Net.